# Transforming dummy variables to single column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following table in R which lists a person race, gender, age, and cholesterol test. age and cholesterol test are displayed as dummy variables. age can be categorized as low, medium, or high, while cholesterol tests can be categorized as low or high. I want to transform the age and cholesterol columns to be single columns where low is categorized as 1, medium is categorized as 2, and high is categorized as 3. Cholesterol test can be neigh low or high if a person never took one and should be N/A in the expected output.
I want the solution to be dynamic so that if I have multiple columns in this format, the code would still work (i.e. there may be some new tests, which can be categorized as high, low, or medium as dummy variables).

How can I do this in R?

input:

```
  race  gender age.low_tm1 age.medium_tm1 age.high_tm1 chol_test.low_tm1 chol_test.high_tm1
  <chr>  <int>       <int>          <int>        <int>             <int>              <int>
1 white      0           1              0            0                 0                  0
2 white      0           1              0            0                 0                  0
3 white      1           1              0            0                 0                  0
4 black      1           0              1            0                 0                  0
5 white      0           0              0            1                 0                  1
6 black      0           0              1            0                 1                  0
```

expected output:

```
  race  gender   age  chol_test
1 white      0     1        n/a  
2 white      0     1        n/a
3 white      1     1        n/a
4 black      1     2        n/a
5 white      0     3          3
6 black      0     2          1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could first define a custom function that allows us to recode dummy variables based on their variable names, below called `var_nm2value`.

This function takes the values of the variables as `x` argument. In `dplyr::across` this is the `.x` part. And it takes a list of name-value pairs as `value_ls` argument. The function just loops over the list of name-value pairs, checks if the name in `value_ls` is found in the variable name. To do this it uses `grepl` on `dplyr::cur_column()`. If we have a match then we replace all `1`s with the value from our `value_ls` and we return all other values, that is the zeros, as is.

Then we can define a list of recode values, below `recode_ls`.

Finally, we use `purrr::map_dfc` in a `dplyr::summarise` where we use the variable strings we want to create `"age"` and `"chol_test"`, then ii) `select` only columns which contain this string, and in each iteration we iii) apply `dplyr::across` to recode the values, iv) pipe the result in a `do.call` to get the `max` and finally v) recode `0`s to `NA`:

```r
# custom function to recode  0/1 dummy variables based on their variable name an 
var_nm2value <- function(x, values_ls) {
  for (val in seq_along(values_ls)) {
    if(grepl(names(values_ls)[val], dplyr::cur_column())) {
      return(ifelse(x == 1L, values_ls[[val]], x))
    } 
  }
}

# define list of recode values
recode_ls <- list(low = 1, medium = 2, high = 3)

library(tidyverse)

# apply functions to data.frame
df1 %>% 
  summarise(race = race,
            gender = gender,
            map_dfc(set_names(c("age", "chol_test")), # i)
                    function(x) { 
                      select(., contains(x)) %>% # ii)
                        summarise("{x}" := across(everything(), var_nm2value, recode_ls) %>% # iii)
                                    do.call("pmax", .) %>% # iv) 
                                    ifelse(. == 0, NA, .))} # v)
            )) 

#>    race gender age chol_test
#> 1 white      0   1        NA
#> 2 white      0   1        NA
#> 3 white      1   1        NA
#> 4 black      1   2        NA
#> 5 white      0   3         3
#> 6 black      0   2         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your custom function does? For example what is the x argument and what is the values_ls argument?

Comment: @Eisen: I added more explanation about the recode function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(across(contains("_"),  ~  
   . * setNames(1:3, c("low", "medium", "high"))[
     str_extract(cur_column(), "low|medium|high")]))   %>%    
  rename_with(~ str_remove(., "_tm1")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(race, gender), 
    names_to = c(".value", "categ"), names_sep = "\\.") %>% 
  filter(age > 0|chol_test > 0) %>% 
  select(-categ) %>% 
  mutate(chol_test = na_if(chol_test, 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  race  gender   age chol_test
  <chr>  <int> <int>     <int>
1 white      0     1        NA
2 white      0     1        NA
3 white      1     1        NA
4 black      1     2        NA
5 white      0     3         3
6 black      0     0         1
7 black      0     2        NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(race = c("white", "white", "white", "black", "white", 
"black"), gender = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), age.low_tm1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), age.medium_tm1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L
), age.high_tm1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), chol_test.low_tm1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), chol_test.high_tm1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"))
```

Comment: I don't really understand this solution. This doesn't give me the expected output as I'm getting a lot more rows then expected

Comment: Column 5 shows `chol_test` as 3 in the expected output because in the input `chol_test.high_tm1` is 1 which indicates it as high. The expected output is just the top few records of my data frame. As I stated in my question I want to map "high" to 3.

Comment: Are you getting more than 6 rows in this solution?